# Webmatrix - displaying relevent data from joined SQL tables

Tags: c#, sql, razor, inner-join, webmatrix

I'm stuck doing a listing page on a new site.

I have 2 tables in my database, **Location** and **Location_Images**, with a common field **location_id** in each.

I'm wanting to create a list of locations where each location's *name* is displayed  alongside its related *images*.

Here's my code:

```
var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
var selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Location";
var searchTerm = "";
var selectedPlace = db.Query(selectCommand, searchTerm);

var selectImagesCommand = "SELECT loc_image_url FROM Location_Images JOIN Location ON Location_Images.location_id=Location.location_id";
var selectImagesTerm = "";
var selectedPlacePics = db.Query(selectImagesCommand, selectImagesTerm);


@foreach(var row in selectedPlace)
{
    @row.location_name;

    foreach(var pic in selectedPlacePics)
    {
        <img src="img/locations/@pic.loc_image_url" alt=".">;
    };

 }
```

At this stage ALL images are showing for EVERY location.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, you are getting all the locations right, if that's not what you want, please explain bit more

Comment: I am getting every image in the database displaying under every location rather than just the ones that link to the particular location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single query for this as:

```
SELECT Location .*, Location_Images.loc_image_url FROM Location leftjoin Location_Images ON Location_Images.location_id=Location.location_id";
```

if you want some filters then you can use where clause.

Comment: How would I use this?  Using it for selectCommand has no impact.  Using it for selectImagesCommand results in Location_Images being unrecognised (token error).